# Queue.Count - How does it work?

Tags: c#, queue

can you tell me if after each time I call `Count`, the `Queue` go over all the `Queue` and count or the Queue have a property of `int` Count and each adding/removing it increase/decrease?

Anyway, Is there a better way to know if the Queue is empty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fy0wwyz4.aspx) (1st hit in Google for "queue.count property"):

> Retrieving the value of this property is an O(1) operation.

Comment: I must of skiped it. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe not everyone knows what O(1) means?

Comment: Well, there are many, many explanations about the [big-O-notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) for understanding algorithm costs... so if someone doesn't know about them, do some research and learn about them. **Here's a starter: [Time Complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities) in Wikipedia**

Answer (score 2):

> The capacity of a `Queue<T>` is the number of elements that the `Queue<T>` can store. `Count` is the number of elements that are actually in the `Queue<T>`.
>
> The capacity is always greater than or equal to `Count`. If `Count` exceeds the capacity while adding elements, the capacity is increased by automatically reallocating the internal array before copying the old elements and adding the new elements.
>
> **Retrieving the value of this property is an O(1) operation.**

Taken from the source [`Queue<T>.Count Property` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fy0wwyz4.aspx)

Comment: Don't plagiarize, quote with source!

Answer (score -1):

A better way to know if a Queue is empty is to use `IEnumerable`'s [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx) method.

This way you won't need to iterate over the whole collection simple to know if there's at least one item in the collection when using a Count method.

```
if(myQueue.Any())
{
 // Do something.
}
```

In the case where `Count` is a property there will be a minor performance gain using `Count` vs `Any` however I think that the intent of the programmer is better preserved through `Any` in many cases, especially when the purpose of the check is to see if any items exist or not.

Comment: Why "better"? Check the docs... `Any()` is always going to be at least a tad slower.

Comment: That `Any()` is faster is only true in comparison to `Enumerable.Count()`, and only if the class doesn't implement a fast `ICollection<T>.Count`. One could argue that `Any()` reads better than `Count>0`, but that's only a stylistic choice.

Comment: I say better because the intention of the programmer is clearer in many cases. In the case where Count is a property then `Any` is a tad slower, you are correct.

Comment: @JamieDixon: You wrote: "This way you won't need to iterate over the whole collection simple to know if there's at least one item in the collection." That's a bit misleading in the context of the question asked because for me it seems to imply that checking `Count` of the queue would iterate through all elements.

Comment: The question is about the `Queue<T>.Count` *property*, not the `Enumerable.Count()` method.  `Enumerable.Any` will force the `Queue<T>` to enumerate the first element, if it exists.  If the OP *just wanted* to know if there were any elements in the queue, `queue.Count > 0` (or `queue.Count == `) is faster than `Enumerable.Any`

Comment: You're right @PeterRitchie, it is faster. Speed isn't the only criteria on which I based by opinion of being "better". The OP asked if there is a better way to know if the list is empty. In my opinion the Any method is better choice because it conveys the intention of the programmer better. I'm not saying I'm right. It's my opinion.